# Querying a many to many relationship, and then displaying the results in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid

Can someone please explain clearly how the above would be best approached using MySql and C#. The database and many to many relationship is already created.

Here's how I would approach it which I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing it:

First i'd create an entry in all 3 tables 
Then I would select the entries where the user_id is equal to the one i need in the joining table
Then I would select all entries out of the class_details which match the class_id's associated to that user in the joining table.
Then would i create an inner join and display that?

I basically want to display all the lessons a user is in, having the data stored in a many-to-many relationship. My apologies if this isn't best explained... I don't really know how to word it. Hopefully someone can help :D

The below is a visual representation of what i want. Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: See following link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: How do you want to query? Sql, linq, entity...

Comment: I want to query using Sql. I know how to display the data after i've gotten there. I just don't know what the SQL query would look like to select all entries in the joining table grouped by the user_id... and the get the name of the class_id from the class_Details table. Does that make sense?

Comment: The joining table has user_id and class_id as tables... both are unique values in the user_details and class_details tables.

Example:

user_id 1 is in class_id 1
Class id 1 is English class

How would i query the above to create a table that displays:

Richard Jenkins        English as two separate columns

Comment: Could you write exactly what you want? You are talking about lessons, but I don't see any such a table...

Comment: Sorry Manta, please see updated post. I have added the tables I want to manipulate and join and how i want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT UC.User_ID,U.User_Name,UC.Class_Id,C.Class_Name from dbo.(joining table name)
inner join dbo.user_details as U on U.User_Id=UC.User_ID
inner join dbo.class_details as C on C.Class_Id=UC.Class_Id
```

Comment: Thank you Manta, appreciate that so much!